# Determine the number of elements in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have a js variable that contains some html tags, how can I determine the number of tags inside the variable? Something like this:

```
contents = "<p>something</p><p>something else</p>";
$(contents).find("p").length > 2;
```

Basically, I'm doing a `$(".someClass").each()` and iterating through a bunch of elements - when I encounter a `<p>` tag I'm putting it in the variable with .html() and now I need to know whats inside the variable to make another decision but my approach above isn't working.

Comment: filter is the right answer, but it's odd that you wouldn't just do something like: 

    paragraphs = $('.someClass').find('p');

and then work with that data.  Adding tags to a separate HTML item and then filtering it seems a roundabout way to get array data.

Comment: You're right. I've been trying several things with this and I guess I ended up with a somewhat convoluted approach due to some other constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `.find` to `.filter`.

`.find` searches children, but in your string, all the `<p>` tags are parents, they aren't children of anything.